# C++ function attribute to indicate lifetime of return value is same as argument

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, undefined-behavior

This code has undefined behavior:

```
#include <string>

std::string make_str(const char* s)
{
    return s;
}

const char* get_str(const std::string& s)
{
    return s.c_str();
}

const char* bad()
{
    return get_str(make_str("hello"));
}
```

The bad function creates a temporary std::string and returns a pointer to its data, which is invalid as soon as the function has returned.

GCC 5+ catches this ("function returns address of local variable") but only if compiling with `-O3`.  At more typical optimization levels including `-O2`, GCC compiles it without complaint, even with `-Wall -Wextra`.  Clang never catches it unless you use the experimental `-Wlifetime` feature.

**My question is:** Can we tell the compiler explicitly about such lifetime dependencies, e.g. using an attribute?  For example, I would like to be able to do this:

```
[[lifetime-depends : s]] // hypothetical syntax
const char* get_str(const std::string& s);
```

Or maybe this:

```
const char* get_str(const std::string& s)
  __attribute__((lifetime-depends(0))); // hypothetical syntax
```

I'll accept an answer that works with any official release of GCC or Clang, but prefer GCC 6.1 with C++14.  Clang's experimental `-Wlifetime` is not an answer, because I want to be explicit, not rely on heuristics (which seemingly wouldn't work across multiple translation units anyway).

Alternatively, I'll accept an answer providing reasons why this wouldn't be useful or feasible to implement.

Comment: This was talked about by herb sutter on cppcon 2019. It doesn't really help you right now, but I believe it's a feature that might come in c++20, or later.

Comment: And it's basically `-Wlifetime`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662135/the-purpose-of-the-wlifetime-flag

Comment: The print version of the talk I believe is this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1179r0.pdf

Comment: Just don't return raw pointers anywhere, problem solved.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: `-Wlifetime` is overzealous, it claims `get_str()` returns a dangling reference even if it does `return "";` and ignores the argument entirely.  In other words, it simply assumes the dependency exists--even when the function is trivial and inline!  Given that this sort of false positive is likely to flare up when compiling existing third-party code, I want an explicit attribute, not a heuristic with false positives.  See https://godbolt.org/z/7eRDSI

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So you don't return iterators, ever?

Comment: @curiousguy Very, very, rarely. And very, very, carefully. But I didn't claim I never did it, just that never doing it will solve the problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Many STL functions return iterators. If you don't, you can't write many algo or containers.

Answer (score 4):

### Opinion based answer which does not provide an answer, but questions the idea behind the question (and was too much text for a comment):

IMHO that would imply a quite immense reliability on compiler intelligence to catch user errors, because that is the code you posted, a failure. The standard already covers how to handle lifetimes of temporaries and does consider extending the lifetime in cases the reference is still in use (see draft [n4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) eg. 15.2 Bullet 5). However, your posted example is a different case...

Also, while the Paper [p1179r0](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1179r0.pdf) (comment by P.W) does provide an idea for pointers to objects stored **on the stack** it does not help with objects on the heap. And how should it? Returning a pointer to char (or any type) is not an error... returning a pointer to an array which does not exist anymore, is. How should it know c_str() returns a pointer to an array of a temporary wich does delete in it's destructor (kinda specific, isn't it?)? How to know if the array is destroyed? By looking into the destructor if a delete is done? What if the destructor does not delete? Warn about destructor should delete? What if the `new` was a placement new? What if.... factory pattern...? What if creating pointers for smart pointer (e.g: shared_ptr)...? What if another 200 points... Managing lifetime on the heap, would mostly result in garbage collection.

The warning you get is `function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]` which, I think, has nothing to do with your code, but is more an "accident" caused by short string optimization. SSO optimized `std::string` **does** return a pointer to a local as the message says... Simple test, make your string longer than 16 chars, the warning [disappears](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/725b9e2bc7f328f3)...

Comment: BTW the SSO makes `string` as non standard practice container. Containers don't have elements inside them. Swap doesn't invalidate iterators, in common practice.